# VS, Resharper, Karma, and AngularJS template unit testing with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, resharper

I have an angular js project with a .Net/C# backend. Some of the JS has unit tests, but at least one team member feels like having to jump out to the command line is a high enough barrier where he doesn't want to write unit tests. So I'm trying to get them to run from within VS with Resharper.

The problem is that I have directives in there with html templates. Every resource I found about how to handle that is to use the ng-html2js preprocessor in karma. None of the Resharper documentation tells you directly how to point to a karma.conf file so that that stuff can happen, and I haven't found any resources that suggest there's an alternate way to handle this.

According to the Resharper docs, you can use an html test harness, but I haven't found anything that suggests you can run karma from a test harness. I inherited this project recently, and I'd like to start by trying to address objections by team members rather than telling them to just suck it up and do it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction (**of how to launch karma with an html harness or how to do preprocessing some other way**)?

Comment: i'm familiar with R# but not with respect to running ng tests. have you looked at the R# Javascript specific test settings, ie this page? http://imgur.com/Rq2yh7E

Comment: No of course I never consult documentation or try anything before asking SO questions. That's why I didn't mention anything about the html harness part in my question.

Comment: i gave you a disclaimer that is just harsh

Comment: I tend to think it's kind of harsh to assume that someone hasn't done the basic stuff they should before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

We have almost the same setup in our project. The .net/c# backend, and a lot of client stuff (JS, scss, html). We run our build/test through [Gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/). Gulp is a streaming build system, very fast - and easy to configure. Also has lots of plugins for common tasks.

To kick off the karma runner from gulp, you can create a task in your gulpfile like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma').server;

/**
 * Run test once and exit
 */
gulp.task('test', function (done) {
  karma.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
    singleRun: true
  }, done);
});
```

Then we use a Visual Studio extension called [Task Runner Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708). This extension lets you execute any Gulp task or target inside Visual Studio. You can also bind any Gulp task or target to a Visual Studio event, such as Build and Solution Open. That way you can run certain tasks when you build your project or run Gulp Watch when the solution is opened.

[image]

Comment: Because I'm not using require.js and haven't ever, I'm not sure how to translate what you have there to what I need. Also, I'd like to stay with resharper if I can. I don't think it will start me off on the right foot with this team to say "yeah, I couldn't figure this out in resharper, so now we're using gulp instead."

Comment: @AmyBlankenship  require statement is from node.js. Do you use a build system for clientside code? Grunt or gulp are two really great build tools. Runs on nodejs and does minification, annotates angularjs, concatinate files etc. Almost a requirement in todays frontend development. Sure you are not already using one of them? :)

Comment: Visual Studio can build and publish the site. Once the tests are working right, it can run them before publish will work. What's the advantage to adding something else?

Comment: Visual Studio is a great tool, but not perfected for building clientside assets like JavaScript, less/sass/css, html. Grunt or gulp, which are two different tools, on the other hand is built specifically for this use case, and does the job extremely well. A gulp task processing templates, uglifying js, bundling assets, etc etc finishes in just a few micro seconds. Thanks to nodejs and streams, its lightning fast. And, not to forget, it can kick off your testsuite aswell

Comment: And its written in JavaScript, a language your frontend guys already knows pretty well already.